# Wildcard in Java doesn't work for Spark cogroup function

Tags: java, oop, generics, inheritance, apache-spark

I am trying to cogroup two RDDs in java, one of the RDD **v2** has type like this: `JavaPairRDD<Key, ? extends Value>` (actually it is defined with `? extends` because it is a function parameter).

Then when I cogroup them, like:

```
void f(JavaPairRDD<Key, ? extends Value> v2){
    TYPE v = v1. cogroup(v2);
    // ERROR. I cannot get the correct type for this cogroup function
}
```

Compiler complains because it cannot infer the type of v2 when I try to get a returned value from this cogroup function.

Interesting is that if I don't care the returned value, simply call:

```
v1.cogroup(v2).collectAsMap();
```

It seems work. At least it can be compiled.

It seems that the java can only accept wildcard (like ) as an argument when it is just defined as wildcard in function parameter. Am I right about it?

I would like to ask whether there is another way to do it correctly? Or maybe I shouldn't do it like this, what is actually wrong here?

Thanks very much.

Comment: How does TYPE relate to Value? And why can't you just use `<Key, Value>`

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it clear. TYPE is the type of returned value of cogroup function. Neither I nor IntelliJ :D cannot infer the returned TYPE of the call v1.cogroup(v2).

Comment: Oh, so this is a generics fail. It should work if you use Object instead of TYPE. Can you include the the function definition of cogroup? (abstract function version) That why I can see what the compiler is trying to return.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the java can only accept wildcard (like ? extends Base) as an argument when it is just defined as wildcard in function parameter.

cogroup is defined in scala, since scala's type system support co-variant inheritence, its interface doesn't contains the keyward extends for java

```
  def cogroup[W](other: JavaPairRDD[K, W]): JavaPairRDD[K, (JIterable[V], JIterable[W])] =
    fromRDD(cogroupResultToJava(rdd.cogroup(other)))
```

But in Java, if the parameter in function signature doesn't has wildcard, the argument when it is called must NOT be some type defined as wildcard.

Comment: How to use `cogroup` for large datasets like when I use `collect()` it throws out of memory exception `rdd1 = rdd2.cogroup(rdd3).collect`. Can you help on this issue [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47180307/how-to-use-cogroup-for-large-datasets]. can partitioning help I'm new to spark any help to resolve this. Or is there is any way we can mimic cogroup.